# How to create view based on multiple tables which only have a subset of common attributes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables whose fields - except add_date - are not related to each other (theoretically). I would like to create one view where I can see the changes in these tables ordered by date:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| add_date |  table1.f1 |            |            |           |            |
| add_date |            |  table2.f1 |            |           |            |
| add_date |            |            | table3.f1  |           |            |
...
etc
...
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

And question 2: what if some fields are shared but not always? For example:

```
table 1: payment history (user, value, currency, add_date)
         for example payment to virtual wallet but
         it can also to be a payment for order or
         payment for other things

table 2: purchases (user, product_id, add_date, order_id)

table 3: withdraws (user, value, add_date)

maybe auxiliary table in this case: orders but not in any case
```

I want to create a one history of changes for several tables.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` to select from your individual tables and make sure that your `SELECT` statements contain the same column names substituting `NULL` where a name doesn't exist in the table.

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS 
SELECT add_date,
    t1.somecolumn col1,
    NULL col2,
    NULL col3
FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    add_date,
    NULL col1,
    t2.anothercolumn col2,
    NULL col3
FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT
    add_date,
    NULL col1,
    NULL col2,
    t3.yetanothercolum col3
FROM t3
```